# re enter canada

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas, eta

Is there actually a specific time frame you are supposed to spend outside the country before returning? If anyone could shed some light on the situation it would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal rule requiring a minimum stay. As long as you are able to present yourself as a visitor who is likely to leave at the end, you should be fine.

Comment: @YatesJohn see https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/115723/58919 for an answer to that question.