# Minimum time between visits to Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, australian-citizens

I am an Australian and lived in Canada for two years on a working holiday visa (IEC) but now expired.

I have an eTA. Is there a specific time you must spend away from Canada before re entering again for a holiday?

Edit: thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any hard rule. Presuming you are travelling on an eTA, the border officer will decide if / how long to let you stay (for a visitor, normally up to 6 months), and this will depend on whether they think you appear to be a genuine visitor or not.

So the answer depends on what you were doing in Canada before you left in March, and how long you intend to stay this time. For example, if you visited for two weeks in March and want to visit for another two weeks in June/July, that would probably be fine (as it's much less than the total 6 months and overall you are spending more of your time in Australia than Canada).

If you previously used the full six month visitor period, and now you're coming back for another long time period, they may ask some more questions about what you're doing and how you're funding yourself (you are now looking like you will spend more time in Canada than Australia, which is not what a visitor does).

Comment: If I were a border agent, I would wonder how you can leave work for 2 months after working there for under 5 months.